# Aggregate County Data into State Data

Tags: r, indexing, match, aggregate

I have a county dataset that I want to convert into aggregate data for the whole state. It describes COVID cases for each county by date that I want to have total state cases by date.

For example, the first county dataframe might look like this for dates and cases:

```
data_sample <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"), cumulative_cases = c(4,6,10,3,5,11))
```

I tried writing my own function to solve the issue by making a new dataframe with only one row of each date and cumulative cases, then adding up all the cases that match that date from the first dataframe. Unfortunately the matching is not working.

```
case_date_aggregator <- function(common_date){
  for (x in common_date){
  if (x == cumulative_cases_df$Dates[x]){
    cumulative_cases_df$Cases[x] <- cumulative_cases_df$Cases[x] + county_covid_data$cumulative_cases[x]
  }}
}
case_date_aggregator(county_covid_data)
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Consider `rbind` of all county data sets and then call `aggregate` + `sum`.

Comment: Your function definition expects a date column where in the function call you are giving it a whole dataset.